# Tap interface is not receiving packets

Tags: linux, interface, scapy, tcpdump, tap

I'm configuring a tap interface and trying to send and receive packets through it,
i configure it like this:

> ```
> ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap multi_queue
> ip linke set tap0 up
> ```

i'm using scapy to send traffic to the interface,
the command is :

> ```
> p = Ether()/IP()
> sendp(p, iface = 'tap0')
> ```

using

> `tcpdump -i tap0 -vvven -vlan`

and didn't catch any packets.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thank you for the information,
if interested i asked here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332810/tap-interface-is-not-receiving-packets